# Synchronizing different nodes on different machines

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What would be the best approach to synchronize two ROS2 nodes (i.e. a common shared clock/time) on two different machines, connected over a wireless network?

At present I've implemented a third node on one of the machines providing a clock, but apparently there is a slight delay/latency of 5-20ms on the other machine, which is variable, and thus hinders the accuracy of time readings.

Is this delay caused/affected by ROS or solely by the network configuration? Is there any tool built into ROS that can help with precise syncrhonization?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373636/synchronizing-different-nodes-on-different-machines/) by [joaocandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/44860/joaocandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What would be the best approach to synchronize two ROS2 nodes (i.e. a common shared clock/time) on two different machines, connected over a wireless network?

A non ROS solution: using `ntp` or `chrony` (or perhaps even something using `ptp`).

Time-synchronisation across different machines is expressly *not* a responsibility of ROS, as there are well established protocols and tools to do that, and it's largely orthogonal to what ROS was created for.

> Is there any tool built into ROS that can help with precise syncrhonization?

No. See my earlier comment.

> At present I've implemented a third node on one of the machines providing a clock,

Are you publishing to the `clock` topic? Note that topic is not intended to be used for (wall) clock synchronisation across multiple machines.

See also: [Clock and Time](https://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html) on the ROS 2 Design site.

> but apparently there is a slight delay/latency of 5-20ms on the other machine, which is variable, and thus hinders the accuracy of time readings.

Tools like `ntp` and `chrony` have built-in systems to compensate for transmission delays and similar challenges which come with time-synchronisation across multiple machines and using COTS networking infrastructure.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joaocandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/44860/joaocandre/) on 2021-03-09**:
I'll check `ntp` and `chrony`, they seem to be what I'm looking for. My particular setup involves a Raspberry Pi acting as access point to another computer, thus there is no internet access, but I'm not looking at precise time values, I just need both machines to share clock/time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:
That would be what `chrony` is specifically for I believe.

**Comment by [joaocandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/44860/joaocandre/) on 2021-03-09**:
I'm indeed publishing to `\clock`, mostly for simplicity/verbosity, but what exactly would be the difference in using a different topic?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:\

> but what exactly would be the difference in using a different topic?

the comment was about the approach, not about the specific name of the topic.